# How to make Shiny click input on plot remain?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

I've been having a problem with a reactive plot in R's Shiny package. I would like to colour certain variables based on clicking one variable. Below is a rather contrived example using mtcars that highlights based on cylinder. The initial colouring works, but disappears straight away.

server side:

```
#server. R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)

function(input, output)
{


output$plot <- reactivePlot(function()
{
 if (is.null(input$clicker) == TRUE){
  graph <- ggplot()+
    theme_bw()+
    geom_point(data = mtcars, 
               aes(x = disp, y = cyl))+
    guides(color=FALSE)+
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    labs(x = "Displacement",
         y = "Cylinders")
  return(graph)
}
else{
  x <-reactive({ 
    x <- nearPoints(mtcars, input$clicker, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
                    addDist = TRUE, xvar = "disp", yvar = "cyl")[1,2]
  })

  print(x())

  mtcars$colour <- NA
  myval <- x()
  mtcars$colour[which(mtcars$cyl == myval)] <- "var"
  plot <- ggplot()+
    theme_bw()+
    geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl != myval,], 
               aes(x = disp, y = cyl, color = colour))+
    geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl == myval,], 
               aes(x = disp, y = cyl, color = colour), size = 4)+
    guides(color=FALSE)+
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    labs(x = "Displacement",
         y = "Cylinders")
  return(plot)
}
})
 }
```

UI side:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

 sidebarLayout(position = "right",
            sidebarPanel(
              h3("Instructions"),
              helpText("Lorem Ipsum.")
              ),
            mainPanel(
              plotOutput('plot', click = "clicker")
            )
)
)
)
```

Is there a variable in the click selection I have missed to make the variable remain? I have used this in examples and it was okay, so I'm guessing it's something to do with the actual plot rendering? Apologies in advance for the daft question..

Comment: u should store them in a `reactiveValue()`. For an example see here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-clustering.html

Comment: @BigDataScientist thank you for that. I've been cobbling together examples, so assumed it was a clumsiness on my part.

Comment: nono, code looks fine. Does it already answer your question?

Comment: Sadly not, @BigDataScientist (or at least how I went about it). The same thing happens, I click on a variable, it highlights, then returns to default a second or so later. Thank you regardless.

Comment: make an edit and share your code, then we can take a look

Comment: @BigDataScientist okay, done. I've used a reactive, but I'm assuming wrongly still, is it because of the assignment being within the if maybe?

Comment: one error that one can see quickly is that you should move the `x <-reactive({ ...` outside the `reactivePlot()` function,...

Comment: I tried it both ways, both seemed to have the exact same result.